# setTimeout executes faster than simultaneous setInterval

Tags: javascript

So, I have a `setInterval` and a `setTimeout` running simultaneously in this click-o-meter thing I'm doing: the user enters an specified number of seconds he/she wants the game to run for, and then it counts how many clicks you have done, what was the average time between each click, and the average amount of clicks per second you've made during the specified period of time.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' id='timerInput'></input>
        <button id='btn'>Click</button>
        <script>
            var before;
            var now;
            var clicks = 0;
            var cts = 0; //Stands for 'Clicks This Second'
            var intervals = new Array();
            var cps = new Array();
            var cpsCounter;
            var timer;
            var canContinue = true;
            var timerInput = document.getElementById('timerInput');
            var timerTime;
            var wasBad = false;

            document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
                if(canContinue) {
                    if(clicks <= 0) {
                        if(timerInput.value.replace(/\D/, '') === timerInput.value) {
                            wasBad = false;
                            timerTime = parseInt(timerInput.value.replace(/\D/, '')) * 1000;
                            before = new Date();
                            cpsCounter = window.setInterval(ctsFunction, 1000);
                            timer = window.setTimeout(finish, timerTime);
                        }else{
                            alert('Only numbers please!');
                            wasBad = true;

                        }

                    }else{
                        now = new Date();
                        console.log(now - before);
                        intervals.push(now - before);
                        before = new Date();
                    }
                    if(!wasBad){
                        clicks++;
                        cts++;
                    }
                }else{console.log('Game ended');}
            };

            function ctsFunction() {
                console.log('Clicks this second: ' + cts);
                cps.push(cts);
                cts = 0;
            }

            function finish() {
                console.log('Clicks: ' + clicks);
                console.log('Average Speed (ms): ' + Math.floor(intervals.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;}) / (clicks - 1)));
                console.log('Average Speed (clicks per second): ' + (cps.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;}) / cps.length));
                intervals = new Array();
                console.log('cps.length: ' + cps.length);
                cps = new Array();
                clicks = 0;
                cts = 0;
                window.clearInterval(cpsCounter);
                canContinue = false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, the problem is that when the gmae finishes, that is, when `timer` reaches the end, `ctsFunction()` is supposed to run once more at the last second, so it can register data from it; but `finish()` is executed faster, or prior to `ctsFunction()`, thus clearing the `cpsCounter` interval and not allowing it to do anything on the last second. I've tried adding some extra milliseconds to `timer`, but if you choose to run the game for enough seconds, the same problem will eventually happen (e.g. if you add 1ms, the problem will be solved for up to 2 seconds, but not for more).

Comment: Neither the time you set for a timeout nor the one for an interval are guaranteed times. You just tell the browser that, it should wait at least that time and then call your callback  as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a setInterval and a setTimeout running simultaneously

It will never happens because javascript is a single thread language. There is no matter what is in your code, javascript can't execute two commands simultaneously.

And one more:

> timer delay is not guaranteed. JavaScript in a browser executes on a
>   single thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers)
>   are only run when there’s been an opening in the execution.

Read [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) to understand how javascript timers work.